# How do I send a null variable, instead of a blank one to my sql DB?

Tags: java, sql, insert, null

Whenever someone tries to register using my program, and leaves a non-required textfield blank, my instruction sends a "" (blank) data, instead on a null one, how do I make that the data i'm inserting is null whenever the textfield is blank?
Thanks

Comment: the word NULL is a keyword that can be passed in an insert or update statement

Comment: Your code example is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using raw SQL:

```
insert into mytable values ('foo', null, 'bar')
```

If you're using prepared statements:

```
preparedStatement.setObject(columnIndex, null);
```

---

Using the query from your comment, here's a simple fix: apply `replaceAll()` to change all blanks to  `null`, like this:

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO clientes (Nombre, Telefono, Calle, Numero,Colonia, Municipio, Estado, Codigo_Postal,Sexo,Fecha_nacimiento) VALUES ('" 
+ snombre_cliente + "','" + stelef_cliente + "','" + scalle + "','" + snumero + "','" + scolonia + "','" + smunicipio + "','" + sestado + "','" + scodigop + "','" + ssexo + "','" + sfecha 
+ "')".replaceAll("'\\s*'", "null"));
```

This will replace all quotes separated by any number of spaces (including no spaces) with the word "null".

Comment: It didn't help me, it says that there's a problem with my sintax.
Here's my code for insertion.


` st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO clientes (`Nombre`, `Telefono`, `Calle`, `Numero`,`Colonia`, `Municipio`, `Estado`, `Codigo_Postal`,`Sexo`,`Fecha_nacimiento`) VALUES ('" + snombre_cliente + "','" + stelef_cliente + "','" + scalle + "','" + snumero + "','" + scolonia + "','" + smunicipio + "','" + sestado + "','" + scodigop + "','" + ssexo + "','" + sfecha + "')");`

Comment: Sure you don't want `'\\s*'` in your regex?

Comment: @NovaDenizen Whoops! You're quite right. Thanks for that pickup.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
preparedStatement.setNull(1,java.sql.Types.String)
```